# Ubuntu .run file can not install by Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

i have .run file name ise "muse.run" i ve tried lots of ways to install it, however i cant.

1.way :chmod +x (pathway).run when i did it , line at terminal , repeat again..
2.way : when i drag .run file icon to terminal page, same again..terminal first line ( acerpc@acer-aspire:) repat again and .run file doesnt work..

if you clik there, you can see a problem [terminal pageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu4sB.png)
Have you any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

chmod makes it executable then just  type `./muse.run`

Comment: Do you get any message?

Comment: No, not response me any error message or something.. Only, root line repeats..it brings to start line

Comment: i have 64 bit ubuntu system, if .run file is 32bit app, it may cause this problem?